# Trying to node with Dojo

Tags: dojo

I tried this on dojo 1.6 and doesn't work. How can I do this?

```
var sQuery = "div:not([id$='_Template']) > a." + sControlClass;

dojo.query(sQuery).forEach(function(node) {
    dojo.connect(
        node, 
        'onclick', 
        function() { 
            alert('clicked')
        }
    )
})
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want fire event click over a list of element.

Comment: can you put more code here as it is not clear from the information provided

Comment: HTML-> <a class="botonBorrarLineaLista" onclick="CMMS_DeleteAllControl('{$Name}_{$controlKey}');" title="Eliminar Todo"></a>

Comment: CMMS_DeleteAllControl = var sQuery = "div:not([id$='_Template']) > a." + sControlClass; if(typeof Nodo === 'string')
            Nodo = procesId(Nodo);

        if(typeof propagation !== 'undefined')
        {
            var auxTest = function(event){ event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();};
            jQuery(Nodo).click(auxTest);
        }
        jQuery(Nodo).click();

        if(typeof propagation !== 'undefined')
          jQuery(Nodo).off('click', auxTest);

Comment: Please edit your original post to put all relevant code readably in one place.  Your comments are also somewhat confusing since they only reference jQuery, not Dojo.  Assuming `sQuery` actually matches things in the document, your original code works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace `onclick` by `click`:

```
var sQuery = "div:not([id$='_Template']) > a." + sControlClass;
dojo.query(sQuery).forEach(function(node) {
    dojo.connect(
        node, 
        'click', 
        function() { 
            alert('clicked')
        }
    )
})
```

Comment: Either `onclick` or `click` would work with `dojo.connect`.

Comment: True, My bad... Anyhow, it require more process to remove the "on" so better not use "onclick"